# Rails-ujs doesn't work in Capybara tests in Rails 7 (with Selenium driver)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-ujs

I've connected @rails/ujs, pinned it and included in js files. And I see that code works as I expect, when I try to do it on development server. But when I launch my capybara tests with selenium driver, I see in logs, that form (which has `remote: true` flag) submitted as HTML.

Here is my code:

**views/articles/index.html.slim**

```
= form_tag root_path, method: :get, remote: true, data: { controller: 'forms', forms_target: "form" }, id: :search_form  do
  = label_tag :query, t('artiles.search')
  = text_field_tag :query, nil, placeholder: t('articles.enter_your_search_query_here'),  data: { action: "input->forms#search" }
  = submit_tag t('buttons.find')

#articles
  = render 'articles', articles: @articles
```

**app/javascript/controllers/forms_controller.js**

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "form" ]

  search() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      Rails.fire(this.formTarget, 'submit')
    }, 200)
  }
}
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.where(
      'title LIKE :query OR body LIKE :query',
      query: "%#{params[:query]}%"
    )
  end
```

**articles/index.js.erb**

```js
articlesTable = '<%= j(render 'articles', articles: @articles) %>';

container = document.getElementById('articles')

container.innerHTML = articlesTable
```

**spec/acceptance/index_page_spec.rb**

```rb
...

  context 'when user fills search form with existing value', js: true do
    before do
      fill_in 'query', with: target_article.title
      find("input[name='commit']").click
    end

    it "User sees only target article on the page" do
      (articles - [target_article]).map(&:title).each do |title|
        expect(page).not_to have_text(title)
      end

      expect(page).to have_text(target_article.title)
    end
  end

...
```

And when I launch some js file on the page (for example, send AJAX requests), I see them in test logs, therefore I see, that selenium driver works. I think, I've connected rails-ujs not properly, but not sure, what exactly I have missed. Can anyone help please? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: One of possible solutions is set up `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome`. (And install chromedriver for that). But the core of the problem I still don't know.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue with Turbo. Works in development environment (no errors in JS console), but Turbo never loads when running my feature specs. Wonder if it could be importmap related, as my importmapped /app/javascript/application.js doesn't seem to get loaded at all in the test 

Comment: @rogerkk no, I took the solution from the first comment above. But it would be great, if you find any others and share with us here )

Comment: Will try to remember, should I happen to find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

If it works in development env but not in test env you most likely have an error in one of your JS files. In the development mode each JS file is loaded separately so an error in one won't affect the others. However, in test (and production) mode the files are concatenated together which means an error in one JS file can prevent others from running.  Check your browser logs in development mode for JS errors and fix them.

Comment: I've noticed, that in Firefox on console they fire error, but, according to (importmap-rails)[https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#expected-errors-from-using-the-es-module-shim], this is ok and shims used for that. Thats why it works. I assumed that the problem is in that. And after I set up `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome`, I found that in Chrome all my tests runs successfully. The core problem I still don't know, though.